# How to use doc.replaceText for the title of a Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

Context: I have a folder full of Google Docs that have numbered information on them. I've provided a [dummy folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3jEfgtM2Y--NEdFREJmNDBmMWs) to give you an idea. Basically I'm looking to replace "File 16" with "File 17", "File 17 with File 18" i.e  "File X" with "File X+1" **both within the document, and in the title.**

By using doc.replaceText and a [Universal Find and Replace](https://ctrlq.org/code/19926-universal-find-replace-in-google-drive) function online, I was able to make a for loop for this exact scenario, and it works perfectly within the contents of a Document. I had to loop it in reverse order so 16 -> 17 wouldn't turn into 16 -> 17 -> 18. The full code and app script is in the folder I provided, but here is the for loop in particular:

```
for (i = 30; i > 10; i--) {
   var v = i + 1;
   doc.replaceText("File " + i, "File " + v);
};
```

I am looking for a way to use a similar for loop to replace parts of the **titles of the Docs** themselves. So to change "Title 16" to "Title 17", "Title 17" to "Title 18", etc. Is there a function within Google App Scripts that would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Document class allows you to make changes at the level of an individual document. replaceText() is the method of the Body class and can't be used in this scenario.

Use DriveApp to access files at file system level. getFiles() returns an instance of the FileIterator class, which is a linked list of nodes. Each node references the next node in a list - if next() returns 'null', it signals the end of the list. The downside is that you can only read files from beginning to end, no skipping.

```
function assignFileNames(){

var iterator = DriveApp.getFolderById(yourFolderId).getFiles();
var file;
var i=0;

while(iterator.hasNext()) {

i++;
file = iterator.next();
file.setName("name " + i);


}

}
```

You could achieve the same result by using DocumentApp and opening each file by name or id, but that would be slower and less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there's also another factor at play. In reality the titles of the Docs have a lot of information that I want to keep, but only change a number that's found in the middle of them. So something like:  

"File 16 - Unique string of text"  
"File 17 - Some other piece of text"  
"File 18 - More, completely different text"  
  
I want to keep all of that, but add +1 to each of the numbers after "File", which I was able to do with a function like replaceText().